# Website manifest.json does not meet requirements

Tags: javascript, json, .net, .net-core, lighthouse

I am trying to add a manifest.json to my website. I am doing an asp.net core project and I have my file stored at wwwroot/manifest.json. But google lighthouse tells me that the manifest didnt meet the requirements with the reason "no manifest fetched". The manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "start_url": "myurl",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/144x144.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you add a `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` to your page's `<head>`?

Comment: Thats where the problem was! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` to my _layout.cs.html – Thank you @Lil Devil